# Compiler & Burner for 8051 Micro-Controller lab?

Tags: software-recommendation, software-sources, compiler, burner

Till now In Windows, I've used *Keil-C* Software to Compile 8051 Micro-Controller Programs in C and *Flash Magic Burner* to burn/dump the software on hardware.

But now I'm having Ubuntu OS. Hence I need an alternate software to compile and dump the program on hardware.

Will you suggest me a standard software for this complete process (except using *Wine*).

Comment: What kind of hardware are you talking about? What kind of interface does it use to receive new code?

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use ***`SDCC`*** is Small Device C Compiler for 8051 Micro-Controller and to have a look, click [**this**](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/).

Else you can use Graphical IDE for MCS-51 based microcontrollers Ubuntu Apps i.e [***MCU 8051 IDE***](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/mcu8051ide/).

[image: MCU IDE 8051]

And also, if you feel to use by means of Wine for burner, then [**this**](http://embeddedrules.blogspot.in/2010/01/install-flash-magic-software-in-linux.html) page might be helpful.

Comment: And if it works, Don't forget to Click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, which means this answer is valid, as regarding to this askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer @Samidha